How can I solve error Cannot access contents of the page which occurs when preview is displayed in safari?
I'm building an extension for safari. I realized when I hold down the link, it shows the preview of the website and it causes errors in background.js.
The preview is like this image.
preview in safari
When I check background.js with web inspector it's saying :

Cannot access contents of the page. Extension manifest must request permission to access the respective host, or have "activeTab" permission with a user gesture.


[Error] Unhandled Promise Rejection: Error: Cannot access contents of the page. Extension manifest must request permission to access the respective host, or have "activeTab" permission with a user gesture.

errors
Due to these errors, even when I choose "Open in new tab", the code in background.js does not run anymore. How can I solve these errors?
I have activeTab permissions in manifest, so I have no idea why it returns this error.


activeTab doesn't work with automatically shown documents, but only with those where the user explicitly invoked your extension. You'll have to add host_permissions for <all_urls> to process previews. 2) Anyway, you can suppress the error either by checking chrome.runtime.lastError if you use callbacks or by using .catch on the promise.


＠woxxom　I'm sorry for late reply. I have  <all_urls>  in host_permissions. The errors are as I mentioned in the question. The errors show up when the preview is shown. but when I click "Open in new tab", nothing happens. The code in background.js is not invoked anymore.

Sounds like a bug in Safari.

＠woxxom I couldn't solve the errors itself but find the solution to run background.js.

I couldn't solve the error itself but managed to run background.js by just simply adding the below code in background.js
browser.tabs.onCreated.addListener(async (tab) => {
  console.log("tab created");
  
});


This code is invoked when users press link and open in new tab.
